# How to handle larger node js request?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, request

How to send a response for large node js request? I have an excel sheet contains 10k items with an updated price. I am uploading the excel from the UI and sending all JSON data in the API for updating the price in the database. Now the request was timed out because of the processing time. How can I handle it in a proper way? How can I send the response after processing all the items?

Comment: An interesting idea would be to move the processing job into a queue and run it when possible. In the meantime, you could poll from the UI this queue and check if the job is done. This way you won't face any timeouts and the actual job could take as long as it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fs.createReadStream` to process large files.

i.e. if you're working on csv files you can process each line like this:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const csv = require("csv-parser")


function processFile() {

    fs.createReadStream("./my-file.csv")
    .pipe(
        csv()
      )
      .on("data", (data) => {
        const value = data.toString()
        // processing
      })
      .on("end", () => {
          console.log('Completed.')
          // send response 
      })
    }

 // watch for file changes. i.e. new. upload
 fs.watch('somedir', (eventType, filename) => {
    if (filename === 'my-file.csv' && eventType === 'change') {
        processFile();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to upload the excel from the UI and send the response after processing all the items.

Comment: I've amended code example. Use `fs.watch` to check directory for file changes, when new file is uploaded, then process it with `fs.createReadStream()` and send response back on `"end"` event. I assumed you can upload file via UI. It doesn't timeout on that...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you suggest if I send one file from the UI to the backend for processing, first I am sending one response for the file uploading(like successfully uploaded the file) and then how can I send the status after processing all data?